# Assigning event id with start/stop and nulls in between

Tags: sql-server, time-series

I have a large series of event data that I need to categorize upwards in granularity where one or many events occur during a larger event.

The parameters to define those events are done. What I need now is to add an ID to the larger events where the next id starts when the prior event ends (start_end). There may be many NULLS in between start and end, or none.

My requirements are:

- Get the result of the right 4 columns from the 3 left columns below.
- I don't care what happens before the first start or after the last end
- seqnum is partitioned by user_id, restarting with each user. doesn't matter if new_id does.
- Each seqnum has a corresponding start/end timestamp, as does each start_end that is not null (excluded for brevity)
- single in start_end = just one original event is a larger event

How do I populate new_id?

| user_id | seqnum | start_end | --> | user_id | seqnum | new_id | start_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | NULL |  | a | 1 | NULL | NULL |
| a | 2 | end |  | a | 2 | NULL | end |
| a | 3 | start |  | a | 3 | 1 | start |
| a | 4 | NULL |  | a | 4 | 1 | NULL |
| a | 5 | NULL |  | a | 5 | 1 | NULL |
| a | 6 | end |  | a | 6 | 1 | end |
| a | 7 | single |  | a | 7 | 2 | single |
| b | 1 | start |  | b | 1 | 3 | start |
| b | 2 | NULL |  | b | 2 | 3 | NULL |
| b | 3 | end |  | b | 3 | 3 | end |
| b | 4 | single |  | b | 4 | 4 | single |

Comment: So, if I am understanding correctly, you just want a value that increments *after* each `'end'` or `'single'` value for `start_end`?

Comment: Why is seqnum continuous if it's partitioned?

Comment: @Larnu correct, just a value that increments after each 'end' or 'single' value for 'start_end'

Comment: @Stu because it was early in the morning and I neglected that when typing in the example. edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a conditional cumulative `COUNT`:

```sql
COUNT(CASE WHEN start_end IN ('end','single') THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY seqnum
                                                                ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS new_id
```

If you want `NULL` instead of `0`, then wrap the whole expression in a `NULLIF` or use `SUM` instead of `COUNT`.